# iPad Pro resolution when running Air Apps / Actionscript

Tags: ios, ipad, actionscript, air

On a retina iPad an Adobe Air based App can address 2048x1536 pixels which is 4x3 aspect ratio. This works great as the non retina iPad is exactly half the resolutions but the same aspect ratio. I can be assured as to the layout regardless of the device.

The iPad pro is now released and has a higher resolution than the iPad retina along with a different aspect ratio.

My app will scale just fine to any aspect ratio, however the Native Capabilities object in Air is reporting the iPad pro as 2048x1536, when it is in fact 2732x2048.

Why is Native Capabilities reporting the wrong resolution and what is happening to the extra screen area, is the iPad stretching, zooming or leaving blank.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding Air's support of the iPad Pro new resolution and icon size there are two open enhancement requests:

- https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=4094365
- https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=4071474

I would go and add your `vote` to each.

> what is happening to the extra screen area, is the iPad stretching, zooming or leaving blank.

I, personally, do not have an iPad Pro to test, you could send me one... ;-), but I would create an image at the `reported` capabilities (2048x1536) and embed it on a test app for display to see what happens. I am *assuming* from other's iPad Pros running `non-optimized apps`, that the image will be upscaled, but will look decent... Apps that were barely acceptable in terms of upscaling on iPad 3, iPad 4, iPad Air, iPad Air 2 @ 1536 x 2048 sincee will look really bad...

With the same iPad aspect ratio and 264 ppi as the rest of the iPad family as long as your assets are based on Apple's @2x high-resolution modifier and your screen layout is using logical resolutions for control layout your app should be "OK" in terms of scaling, if your assets as not @2x style, then upscaling will look blocky of course...

FYI: the logical layout resolution of the iPad Pro would be 1024 x 1366 and thus if your app follows that layout res and thus 4:3 for all iPads, you should not see any "stretching"...

Comment: If I had access to an iPad pro I would simple test. However, the real issue is why is the resolution been reported incorrectly!

Comment: As reported in the bugs, Air does not know how to report against a device id of "iPad6,8", you can also check the air beta forums as this has been reported there also

Comment: Also I would recommend including @3x assets as this 'kind-of' the reverse of the iPhone6s that renders at a higher resolution than their native resolution and then down-sample to actually display the app

Comment: In Adobe Air I do not use @3x/@2x, I address the entire stage and scale as needed. My app is 100% vector based so this all works great, assuming I know the actual size of the stage,